# Нужно ли здесь ставить тире? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, тире

**Если ты не заметила — я про тебя забыл.**

Уместно ли здесь тире?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова, что означает (М). Если такой вопрос уже был, обычно добавляют порядковый номер

Comment: С порядковыми номерами можно запутаться. Я решила, что в повторяющемся вопросе можно брать в скобки инициалы спрашивающего. Пару раз я такие правки делала. Пока претензий не было. ТАК - нельзя?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Не мне решать, надо обсудить на Мете

Comment: Не мне (решать) - тем более. Но модераторы пока не пинали. Если что НЕ ТАК, Вы мне скажите! На Мете я Вам сообщала: если и виновата, не совсем права, то - понятлива.

Comment: @М_Г МЫ  - "послесоветские ньюевропейцы" (мой термин) - очень покладисты: английского не знаем, русского не знаем... Очень удобно: КАК  скажете - ТАК и знаем...

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова,  Термин мне очень понравился, но все это к делу не относится, и лучше его вынести в чат (а как - не знаю).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В данном случае тире *замещает* недосказанное и опущенное в тексте. Полный текст мог быть примерно таким:

> Если ты не заметила [*перемен, скажу тебе прямо:*] я про
>   тебя забыл.

Запятая вместо тире вряд ли была бы здесь уместна: получилось бы условное предложение (СПП с придаточным условия), две части которого не стыкуются по смыслу (ложный смысл: "*забыл про неё, если предположить, что она чего-то не заметила*").

Answer (score 0):

Тире уместно, а правило, я думаю, подходит такое: *Вводные предложения имеют значения, близкие к значениям вводных слов и сочетаний. Они выделяются запятыми, либо, значительно реже, – знаком тире* ([Справочник по пунктуации](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach2))

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

*И за это, если ты заметила, тебя вокруг тоже никогда не любили*. [Э. С. Радзинский. 104 страницы про любовь (1964)]

*Если ты заметил, я не счел это необходимым.* [Мариам Петросян. Дом, в котором... (2009)]